# Can bitcode still be disable on Xcode 9.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

Can once still be able to disable bitcode on Xcode 9.2?  I looked into Build Settings tab under project.  But there was not one.

Comment: You need to select `All` tab

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Xcode 9.2 also you can disable bitcode. Today I just disabled bitcode in Xcode 9.2 and successfully uploaded game to iTunesConnect.

[image]